# Stop refetch data in react-query

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query

In react-query how can stop refetch data? It happens when I change the browser tab and return, when I resize the browser window and sometimes without understanding why. It's not a background thing, I needed a preloader but in this case it's annoying.
In useQuery I tried to set staleTime and cacheTime but no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing the `QueryClient`, you can configure various default options for queries. You can configure `staleTime` as well as `cacheTime` to ensure that data is not refetched unless it is stale. In your case, you mention the data being refreshed when you re-focus the browser windows. In this case, you may want to specifically look into `refetchOnWindowFocus` options.

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1 hour in ms
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1 hour in ms
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false, // Disables automatic refetching when browser window is focused.
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: It works well, thank you!

Comment: the default value for refetchOnWindowFocus respects staleTime, so technically, setting staleTime alone should work.